# How to detect sibbling subpackage imports to test architectural coupling rules

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, decoupling

## Project directory structure:

I've got a Python 3 project with following directory structure (a src package and test outside source package):

```
root/
├── readme.md
├── setup.py
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── helpers.py
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── decode_a.py
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── decode_b.py
│   └── coupling.bat
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sibbling_coupling.py
    └── test_coupling.py
```

Source folder is divided into several sibbling subpackages: **common** with common helpers, and **a** and **b** subfolders.

## Following design architectural rules have been defined:

- **common** subpackage: any sibbling subfolder (a, b) can import from common
- **a** subpackage: no sibbling subfolder (common, b) can import from a
- **b** subpackage: no sibbling subfolder (common, a) can import from b

This is a simplified example, but in a real project it's not strange to find some imports breaking these rules. E.g: Content of src/decode_b.py

```
from a.decode_a import decode_a      << import breaking coupling rules: From b imports a 
from common.helpers import to_level


def decode_b(string):
    level = to_level(string)
    result = decode_a(level)
    return result
```

## So a mechanism is needed to check architectural coupling rules:

#### First I thought if possible to detect inside a.**init** the origin of the import.

But I haven't found anything that let me raise an exception or log an error.

#### Second I made a windows bat to detect it (src/coupling.bat):

```
findstr /b /c:"from a." /s /d:common;b  *.py
findstr /b /c:"from b." /s /d:common;a  *.py

findstr /b /c:"import b." /s /d:common;a  *.py
findstr /b /c:"import a." /s /d:common;b  *.py
```

- Pros: this is a quick solution and it detects the breaking import (see following output)
- Cons: this is windows dependent

```
b_decode.py:from a.a_decode import decode_a
```

#### And third I made a python equivalent solution using glob (test/test_coupling.py):

```
def test_options_file():
    subpackage_coupling = SibblingCoupling()
    forbidden_imports = subpackage_coupling.check()
    assert forbidden_imports == []
```

With a sibbling_coupling.py file to make the check:

```
class SibblingCoupling:
    PYTHON_FILES = "*.py"
    SRC_PATH = "src"

    # Key = subpackage_name, value = list of allowed subpackages to be imported (apart from itself)
    COUPLING_RULES = {
        "common": [],
        "a": ["common"],
        "b": ["common"],
    }

    def __init__(self):
        working_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd()
        self.src_path = working_dir.parents[0] / self.SRC_PATH
        self.subpackages = set(self.COUPLING_RULES.keys())
        self.forbidden_imports = []

    def check(self):
        for name, allowed_subpackages in self.COUPLING_RULES.items():
            self._check_subpackage(name, allowed_subpackages)
        return self.forbidden_imports

    def _check_subpackage(self, name, allowed_subpackages):
        allowed_coupling = set(allowed_subpackages)
        allowed_coupling.add(name)
        forbidden_coupling = self.subpackages - allowed_coupling
        for file in self._files_inside_subpackage(name):
            self._check_file(file, name, forbidden_coupling)

    def _files_inside_subpackage(self, name: str):
        result = (self.src_path / name).rglob(self.PYTHON_FILES)
        return result

    def _check_file(self, file, name, forbidden_coupling):
        for forbidden_subpackage in forbidden_coupling:
            text = file.read_text()
            forbidden_type_from = re.findall(
                f"^from {forbidden_subpackage}.* import .*$", text, re.MULTILINE
            )
            forbidden_type_import = re.findall(
                f"^import {forbidden_subpackage}.*$", text, re.MULTILINE
            )
            if forbidden_imports := (forbidden_type_from + forbidden_type_import):
                self._add_forbidden_imports(forbidden_imports, name, forbidden_subpackage)

    def _add_forbidden_imports(self, forbidden_imports, name, forbidden_subpackage):
        forbidden_results = [
            f"{name} imports {forbidden_subpackage}: {forbidden}"
            for forbidden in forbidden_imports
        ]
        self.forbidden_imports += forbidden_results
```

When I run using pytest, test fails as expected with following assertion error:

```
Expected :[]
Actual   :['b imports a: from a.decode_a import decode_a']
```

#### Question:

Isn't there any other smarter / more pythonic / or not so verbose solution to enforce design architectural rules (for any operating system).

Note: This question is based on python 3.8.2